# friendly_id - Isolating the slugs to a separate table

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-url, friendly-id

Is there any possibility to have slug field in the common/separate table perhaps with Polymorphic association?

For example I have three models `User`, `Product` and `Slug` but the slug field is not present in users and products table. The `slug field` is present in `slugs` table.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRercord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :finders]
  has_one :slug, dependant: :destory, as: :sluggable, class_name: "FriendlyId::Slug"
end
```

**Product Model:**

```
class Product < ActiveRercord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :finders]
  has_one :slug, dependant: :destory, as: :sluggable, class_name: "FriendlyId::Slug"
end
```

**Slug Model**

```
module FriendlyId

  class Slug < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :sluggable, :polymorphic => true

    def to_param
      slug
    end

  end
end
```

I want to find the User record using slug content for example

**User.find("rafiu")** - to fetch the user with slug content of "rafiu"

It should find the user by joining slugs table.

Is there a way to do this?